# On the OEIS sequence A327265

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, oeis

The OEIS sequence https://oeis.org/A327265 starts:

$$1, 2, 5, 11, 19, 31, 51, 89, 123, 151, 179, 181, 180, 365, 634, 657, 656, 655.$$

> $\mathrm{A327265}(n)$ is the smallest $k$ such that $\mathrm{A309981}(k) = n$.

> $\mathrm{A309981}(n)$ is the smallest number $k$ such that the value of $n$ can be deduced given only the values $\tau(n), \tau(n+1), \dotsc , \tau(n+k)$, where $\tau(a)$ is the number of divisors of $a$.

The OEIS sequence https://oeis.org/A309981 starts:

$0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3.$

I want a reference of Jon E. Schoenfield why the first $18$ terms are correct and why.

Comment: do you have a reason think there is an error?

Comment: Jon E. Schoenfield wrote these terms, but I'm not sure if the last $10$ listed terms are correct.

Comment: it's true that the the OEIS entry does not give much explanation for how he computed the larger entries. Perhaps your best bet is to ask him directly.

Comment: But I'm not able to ask him directly. Can someone else ask him directly?

Comment: The pdf of the [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL20/Pinter/pinter3.html) that he mentions at his OEIS user page includes an email address, which you could try contacting him at.

Comment: The paper is related to neither $A327265$ nor $A309981$.

Comment: And I'm not allowed to contact with Jon E. Schoenfield. Possibly someone else can?

Comment: And is $A327265(17)=655$ only conjectural or proved?

Comment: The paper is unrelated but it lists an email address which you could use to contact him. Perhaps I do not understand what you mean by saying you are "not allowed" to contact him.

Comment: I'm not able to contact with him.

Comment: One of the Jon E. Schoenfield's A309981 comments is: I found most of these terms fairly easy to prove; a(49) was interesting, though! I had the idea for this sequence some weeks ago, and worked out the proofs for each of the first 96 terms by hand. (I think a(97) may be 3, but I don't know.) After that, I did a search for the values of n such that a(n)=1 and found A161460, and after seeing R. J. Mathar's manuscript there, I concluded that there probably isn't some easy way to generate lots of terms of this sequence. Does this sequence seem to be of general interest? Suggestions welcome! :-)

Comment: The numbers $131174690735103$ and $32711472211241049663$ are the counterexamples to the R. J. Mathar's conjecture that $A309981(746495)=1$ and in turn they imply that $746495$ isn't in $A161460$.

Comment: Only the upper bounds of $A309981(k)$ were proved without using calculator but were proved to be the exact upper bounds by using a programmable calculator for $k\le96$. For example, he proved by hand the upper bounds for $A309981(k)$, e.g., $A309981(82)\le6$. However, $A309981(82)$ cannot be $\le5$ because this would contradict the corresponding sequence starting with $670762$, so $A309981(82)=6$. He used a programmable calculator for $k≤87$. And $A309981(88)=6$ since this would contradict the corresponding sequence starting with $232$ and $A309981(89)=7$ via start $242510633$.

Comment: I've Jon's email address, I'll ask him whether I can DM it to you or whether he wants to join the discussion here.

Comment: @Max I don't understand your "DM". What is DM here?

Comment: @JovanRadenkovic "DM" is usually used for "direct mesage"... I forgot that SE/MO doesn't allow(?) to DM... But anyway I have the same email address than that on the JIS paper Noam pointed to. I think it should work.

Comment: It is true that $A309981(2916)=2$, while $A309981(2500)=4$. The upper bounds can be easily proved by hand, but the second requires the Aurifeuillian factorization $$x^4+4y^4=(x^2-2xy+2y^2)(x^2+2xy+2y^2).$$ The factorization $$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$ is required to prove that $A309981(35)=1$ and $A309981(99)=1$. Hence the sequences $35,99,2500,2916$ and $A327265$ are disjoint (i.e., with no common terms).

Comment: Also, $191$ is not in $A327265$ since $A309981(191)=2$.

Comment: @NoamZeilberger Can you search for the proof of the first $18$ terms of the OEIS sequence $A327265$?

Comment: The file https://oeis.org/A309981/a309981.txt is interesting but I don't agree on some values, e.g., for n=40 I get m=136 as the next larger m which has t(m,k-1) = t(n,k-1) with notations as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a nice exercise to write out these proofs. I do agree that they should be given somewhere, e.g. on the OEIS wiki. [I just tentatively started such a [page](https://oeis.org/wiki/A309981).] And it is probably somewhat/highly(?) nontrivial to write a program for that.

But in any case, it is clear that any n has a unique "tau signature" t(n) = t(n,k) = (tau(n), tau(n+1), …, tau(n+k)) with some minimal k = A309981(n):

The opposite would mean that there is m > n such that tau(m+k) = tau(n+k) for all k ≥ 0. But we know that for infinitely many k, tau(n+k) = 2 meaning that n+k is a prime. So tau(m+k) = tau(n+k) would imply that prime gaps become periodic, with a period dividing m-n (*), and we know that this isn't the case.

(*) That's slightly ill-formulated but I hope the meaning is clear: m-n does not refer to indices of primes or gaps but to the primes themselves, so the period length in the indices of the gaps would be something like primepi(m+k) − primepi(n+k) with the smallest k such that n+k is prime.

PS: as is written in a comment in oeis.org/A309981 (and Hans Havermann recalled in an email on the SeqFan list), the odd values tau(n+k) corresponding to squares also allow to identify n uniquely.